# Alerta no se muestra cuando lo muestro antes de un re direccionamiento

Tags: php, javascript

Quiero mostrar un mensaje con el error que me genera una sentencia en mi BD  y luego re direccionar a otra pagina, el código es el siguiente:

```
echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Error al Grabar Cheque:'.$arr[2].'");</script>';
sleep(5);
header('Location: index.php?controlador=ChequesController&accion=Listar');
```

$arr[2] contiene el mensaje del error, incluso puse el sleep para demorar la ejecución del re direccionamiento y se pueda ver el error. (solo puedo ver el mensaje si quito la linea del Header). alguna sugerencia?, gracias

Comment: El status code del response es HTTP 302?

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres con Status Code, tengo un error de la bd que quiero mostrar en un alert y despues redireccionar a otra pagina, si pongo todas las lineas si me redirecciona a la pagina pero no muestra el mensaje de error, si quito el redireccionamiento solo me muestra el mensaje y se queda en una pagina en blanco pues no llega a la Vista.

Comment: Abre las herramientas de desarrollo de tu navegador y fijate si el response devuelve HTTP 302. Puedes seguir lo que dice este pst: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el response deveulve como status code HTTP 302 redirect, entonces todo el body del response, en este caso todo el HTML será descartado y simplemente se realizará la redirección a la página destino.

El `sleep` no va a lograr nada porque se ejecuta en el servidor y no en el cliente.

Lo que debes hacer es retornar tu HTML con un `setTimeout` y luego de pasado el intervalo de tiempo hacer la redirección por JavaScript, y sin retornar ningún header.

Ejemplo

```
echo '<script>';
echo '    alert("Error al Grabar Cheque:'.$arr[2].'");';
echo '    window.setTimeout(function() {';
echo '        window.location.href ="<url destino>";';
echo '    }, 5000);';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: Acabo de probarlo, es lo que estaba Buscando. Gracias. problema resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo del motor de PHP (Apache con modphp, Apache con fastcgi, Nginx con php-fpm) puede que sí o sí PHP escriba todo el contenido de una vez en vez de irlo imprimiendo conforme vas poniendo echo.

De no ser el caso, podrías usar `flush`

```
echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Error al Grabar Cheque:'.$arr[2].'");</script>';
flush();
sleep(5);
header('Location: index.php?controlador=ChequesController&accion=Listar');
```

pero puede que incluso eso no te funcione y te des mil vueltas usando otras opciones de PHP. (Mira [esta respuesta en StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870697/php-flush-that-works-even-in-nginx) donde terminaron modificando el php.ini para que funcionara)

Yo lo haría todo con javascript.

```
echo '<script>';
echo 'alert("Error al Grabar Cheque:'.$arr[2].'");';
echo 'window.setTimeout(function() { window.location.href="index.php?controlador=ChequesController&accion=Listar";   },5000);';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: Funciono, problema resuelto. Gracias compañero.